# Wordpress-redirect homepage to index.php

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. My site loads fine when I go to 
`mydomain.com`. Now I have created a page named `Home` and its 
permalink is `mydomain.com/homepage`. 
If I click `home` it does not load the posts.

How do I link `Home` to site's root(index.php) ?

***index.php***

```
<?php

get_header();
?>
<h1>index.php</h1>
<?php 

    if(have_posts()):

    while(have_posts()):the_post();
?>
    <article class="post">
         <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
         <?php the_content(); ?>
     </article>

<?php       
    endwhile;
else:

    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;
?>

<?php 
   get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: Change permalink structure as "Post name" in Settings->permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Go to Settings>Reading>Select "A static page"(radio button) then select your "home"(page) in Front Page:(dropdown).

Hope I can help.

Comment: I have tried that. It loads the index.php but it does not show the posts.

Comment: posts in your home page?

Comment: I have updated my post.  It shows "No content found"

Comment: Does you home page has The Loop?  <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); 
  //
  // Post Content here
  //
 } // end while
} // end if
?>

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I set static page to Home, the parmalink change to mydomain.com and it does not load the posts in index.php

Comment: After setting static page to Home, put The Loop from your index.php to your Home page. I hope I'm understanding this right. You want the posts to show in Home page right? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't seem right, what theme are you using?

anyway if you changed reading settings to display a static page, you can create a file and name it home.php, this file will take over index.php

place there what ever content you want to display as your homepage

Answer (score 0):

In case some one is wondering, how to redirect `Home` link to `example.com`.

It is simple,

WP backend->Appearance->Menus->click custom links->add title(`Home`) and link(`http://example.com`)->Add to menu.

Hope it helps someone :)